# Обработка зависимых списков(yii2)

Tags: php, yii2

Суть вопроса такова, я настроил зависимые списки, но если в списке одно значение, то его невозможно выбрать (кликнуть по нему для отправки ajax запроса)

```
    $film_id = ArrayHelper::map($films, 'id', 'title');
    $params_film_id = [
        'prompt' => 'Film',
        'onchange' => '
                $.post("index.php?r=order/lists_date&id=' . '"+$(this).val(), function(data){
                    $("select#order-date_id").html(data);
                });',
    ];

    $date_id = ArrayHelper::map($dates_id, 'id', 'date_session');
    $params_date_id = [
        'prompt' => 'Date session',
        'onchange' => '
                $.post("index.php?r=order/lists_session&id=' . '"+$(this).val(), function(data){
                    $("select#order-session_id").html(data);
                });',
    ];


    $session_id = ArrayHelper::map($sessions, 'id', 'time');
    $params_session_id = [
        'prompt' => 'Session',
        'onchange' => '
                $.post("index.php?r=order/lists_ticket&id=' . '"+$(this).val(), function(data){
                    $("select#order-ticket_id").html(data);
                });',
    ];


     <?= $form->field($model, 'film')->dropDownList($film_id, $params_film_id) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'date_id')->dropDownList($date_id, $params_date_id) ?>
     <?= $form->field($model, 'session_id')->dropDownList($session_id, $params_session_id) ?>
```

как можно это обойти?

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере изменил ответ который нам приходит через ajax` /**
     * @param $id
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionLists_date($id)
    {

```
    $countDates = Date::find()
        ->where(['film_id' => $id])
        ->count();
    $dates = Date::find()
        ->where(['film_id' => $id])
        ->all();
    echo "<option>Select date</option>";
    if ($countDates > 0) {
        foreach ($dates as $date) {
            echo "<option value='" . $date->id . "'>" . $date->date_session . "</option>";
        }
    }
}`
```